# Attribute name "checked" associated with an element type "input" must be followed by the ' = ' character

Tags: visualforce, html

I want to have a radio button to be selected as default in VF page.

```
<input type="radio" name="protocol" value="http" checked/>http
<input type="radio" name="protocol" value="https"/>https <br/>
```

But this throws up an error while saving the VF page

> Attribute name "checked" associated with an element type "input" must be followed by the ' = ' character.

Any idea what is the right syntax?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use following syntax:

```
checked="checked"
```

Comment: I couldnt find an answer when i googled it, thought it would be good if i put it out here if someone else had the same issue

Answer (score 1):

It had to be checked="checked"

```
<input type="radio" name="protocol" value="http" checked="checked" />http
```